# Matlab - Use variables to represent e.g. 'filename*.png'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to construct a GUI.Therfore I want the user to input infomation into the GUI and be treated as variables:

The following code line works perfectly:

```
filePattern = fullfile(folder_name, 'filename*.png' );
```

But when I assign the following variables:

```
x = 'filename';
y = '.png';
```

To get the follwing:

```
filePattern = fullfile(folder_name, x * y );
```

I get the error below:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in NameChanger>Plot_Callback (line 157)
filePattern = fullfile(folder_name, x * y );
```

Please help

Comment: Try `filePattern = fullfile(folder_name, [x, '*', y]);`. Both `x` and `y` are strings, so you can't multiply them (`x * y`) -- what you mean is to concatenate them, with an asterisk in between (`[x,'*',y]`).

Comment: It worked, thank you